# Bicycle Generator Help

Tags: battery-charging, generator

I've been finding myself bicycling inside more and more as I'm getting into the whole Zone 2 workouts where I need to be at a steady state as much as possible and that's hard to do biking outdoors. I figured it would be nice to convert some of that work into usable energy. So I looked at bicycle generators and decided to build one.

[image]

Using an old bicycle tire and the bike trainer that I have, I bought a v-belt and a 24V 350W DC motor. I then hooked up the motor to a XT60 plug and plugged it directly into an Ecoflow battery. I assumed that since the Ecoflow has MPPT, reverse current protection, that I wouldn't need a diode or a solar controller. I hopped on the bike and started pedaling.

I noticed that sometimes the Ecoflow would register wattage input that would vary anywhere from 10-80 watts no matter how hard I'm pedaling or when I'm pedaling at a constant rate. I would only see these readings for a second or two before it would fall back down to zero. When there's wattage input into the battery, I noticed some extra resistance would kick in for a few seconds before disappering and the wattage input going to zero. Using my multimeter, at steady state, I'm reading around 30-40V from the motor.

What am I missing here? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a question for the designers of *Ecoflow*. But if you want something designed directly for your purposes, then you may need to design it yourself. I would guess that there are algorithms operating in the *Ecoflow* which may comport poorly to your usage case. This isn't a complaint about *Ecoflow*, which I gather is quite sophisticated and can handle a number of different charging scenarios. It just may be that your hookup isn't one of those they intended. If you proceed on your own, spend time studying systems that are designed to recover braking energy from DC motors.

Comment: Makes sense. I guess I was worried that I was missing something in the circuit but it sounds like this was setup correctly (in theory)? Maybe moving forward what I should do is break the circuit up instead of leaving all the work of processing the input to the Ecoflow. I'm thinking, getting a MPPT controller, 12V car battery, and then after I finish charging the car battery, dump the power into the Ecoflow via 12V cigarette lighter? Is that a sound plan?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.